# PHP Connect Oracle DB using single database Object - Singleton Pattern

Tags: php, oracle, singleton

**PHP Script:**

```
class db_singleton
{
    const ORACLE_HOST = "SOMEVALIDIP";
    const ORACLE_USER = "oracleuser";
    const ORACLE_PASS = "oraclepass";
    const ORACLE_DB = "SOMEVALIDIP/ORACLEDB";

    private static $instance; // stores the instance

    private function __construct() { } // block directly instantiating

    private function __clone() { } // block cloning of the object


        /*public static function getInstance() {

        if(!self::$instance) {
            // instance doesn't exist yet, so create it
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        // return an instance of this class (Database)
        return self::$instance;
        }*/   

    public static function call()
    {
        // create the instance if it does not exist
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            // the ORACLE_* constants should be set to or
            //  replaced with your db connection details
            self::$instance = oci_connect(self::ORACLE_HOST, self::ORACLE_USER, self::ORACLE_PASS, self::ORACLE_DB);
            if(self::$instance->connect_error)
            {
                throw new Exception('Oracle connection failed: ' . self::$instance->connect_error);
            }
        }
        // return the instance
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

To make a query I write below code:

```
$result = db_singleton::call()->query("SELECT * FROM some_valid_table"); 
print_r($result);exit;
```

The above gives exception:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

Not sure about connecting `Oracle DB` usign PHP `Singleton Pattern`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From php.net

```
resource oci_connect ( string $username , string $password [, string $connection_string [, string $character_set [, int $session_mode ]]] )
```

An example:

```
// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'localhost/XE');
```

Comment: Connection is done. But not fetching value for table.

Comment: but the manual saying that the first argument is username, but urs is hostname

Comment: Changed my code to this `self::$instance = oci_connect(self::MYSQL_USER, self::MYSQL_PASS, self::MYSQL_DB);`

Comment: r u trying to connect to mysql database?

Comment: also when querying use the sequence mentioned by @mudasobwa in the answer.

Comment: is this sequence correct `$conn = db_singleton::call();
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM somevalid_table');
oci_execute($stid);
while($result=oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
{
$result_set_array[] = $result;
}` ?

Comment: seems okay. lots of examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php

Comment: But when I call any model from my controller, which extends my `class db_singleton`, it throws exception `Fatal error: Call to private db_singleton::__construct()`.

Answer (score 2):

[`oci_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) returns `resource`. You should use `oci_` functions family to fetch data from DB, like:

```
oci_execute( 
  oci_parse( 
    db_singleton::call(), 'SELECT * FROM some_valid_table' 
  ) 
);
```

More examples are available at the page linked.